# Regex match alphabetic/numeric that is not x

Tags: r, regex

Assume I want to extract all strings starting in either `ftp` or `ftpk` (example made up).

I currently have a solution:

> Get all the strings starting with `ftp` but not those starting in
>   `ftpx` or `ftpc`.

I wonder how I can make it more general (because right now I'm listing the exceptions which can become tedious), something like:

> Get all the strings starting with `ftp` but not those starting in
>   `ftpX` where `X` is any alphabetic/numeric that is not `k`.

```
# Data:
vec <- c("ftp:ladpmxqgvt", "ftpx:xfiwyoloqu", "ftpk:yol.qdsrehn", 
         "ftpc:krjqdzsuhb", "ftpk:yolo.taxukj", "ftp:qvxarpkjid",
         "ebutlngqkr", "yolx.vhznja")

# Current solution (desired output)  
grep("^ftp[^xc]", vec, value = TRUE)
"ftp:ladpmxqgvt"   "ftpk:yol.qdsrehn" "ftpk:yolo.taxukj" "ftp:qvxarpkjid"
```

Comment: This: `^ftpk?:`?

Comment: @ctwheels That would ignore ftp

Comment: @Dason look again.

Comment: doesn't ignore ftp but doesn't exclude ftpc...

Comment: @snoram you said `but not those starting in  ftpx or ftpc` and `Get all the strings starting with ftp but not those starting in  ftpX where X is any alphabetic/numeric that is not k`

Comment: Precisely `grep("^ftpk?", vec, value = TRUE)` would extract those also...

Comment: Will the ftp(possibly k) always be followed by a colon?

Comment: @Dason Probably... but I'm looking for the most general solution for learning purposes.

Answer (score 1):

### Code

[See regex in use here](https://regex101.com/r/L7uZqb/1)

```
^ftpk?:
```

If you don't know if `:` will follow `ftp` you can use the following, which simply ensures `ftp` or `ftpk` is followed by a non-word character:

```
^ftpk?\b
```

---

### Results

#### Input

```
ftp:ladpmxqgvt
ftpx:xfiwyoloqu
ftpk:yol.qdsrehn
ftpc:krjqdzsuhb
ftpk:yolo.taxukj
ftp:qvxarpkjid
ebutlngqkr
yolx.vhznja
```

#### Output

Below lists only matches

```
ftp:ladpmxqgvt
ftpk:yol.qdsrehn
ftpk:yolo.taxukj
ftp:qvxarpkjid
```

---

### Explanation

- `^` Assert position at the start of the line
- `ftp` Match this literally
- `k?` Match `k` literally zero or once
- `:` Match this literally

Answer (score 1):

I think this solution most closely mimics the sentence:

> Get all the strings starting with ftp but not those starting in `ftpX` where `X` is any alphabetic/numeric that is not `k`.

```
grep("ftp(?!k)[[:alnum:]](*SKIP)(*FAIL)|ftp", vec, value = TRUE, perl = TRUE)
```

or

```
grep("ftp(?!(?!k)[[:alnum:]])", vec, value = TRUE, perl = TRUE)
```

Result:

```
[1] "ftp:ladpmxqgvt"   "ftpk:yol.qdsrehn" "ftpk:yolo.taxukj" "ftp:qvxarpkjid"
```

**Note:**

- The first solution uses the `(*SKIP)(*FAIL)` trick to avoid matching particular patterns. In this case, I am using it to avoid matching `ftp` followed by an alphanumeric character except `k`, and matching any `ftp` that was not avoided.
- The second solution is similar, but uses negative lookahead. `(?!k)[[:alnum:]]` matches all alphanumerics except `k`, while `ftp(?!(?!k)[[:alnum:]])` matches `ftp` not immediately followed by any alphanumerics except `k`.
- The advantage of these two solutions is that one can add to the things to avoid. Just add them to `(?!k)[[:alnum:]]` or `(?!(?!k)[[:alnum:]])`.